# Can't get flowtype to work with babel. Unexpected token

Tags: babeljs, flowtype, babel-loader

```
ERROR in ./$Store.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: ./$Store.js: Unexpected token, expected "{" 
(24:39)

import Notification from '../$Notification' 
export class ERStore extends StoreBase implements _Store {
                                       ^
```

Same with "type" and another flow annotations. I've tried to:

1) add @babel/preset-flow

2) add plugin-transform-flow-strip-types

3) add "@babel/plugin-syntax-flow"

4) updated all deps to latest versions available

5) different order of presets

```
.babelrc
    {
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "entry",
      "modules": "auto"
    }],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-flow"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
    "lodash"
  ]
}
```

deps:

```
"webpack": "3.12.0",
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-flow": "^7.2.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^7.2.3",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-stage-3": "^7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
```

UPDATE: 
Interesting, but jest is working fine with babel-jest. 
Loader usage:

```
{
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            babelrc: true
          }
        },
      },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set babel config in webpack.conf file explicitly. 
.babelrc was working only partly.